# How can modulo deal with big float numbers

Tags: python, numbers

Hey i'm trying to use modulo with big float numbers but python don't seems to like those big numbers. My goal is to check if the division of 2 integers give me an integer or not (so if `division_result%1 == 0` or not)

**Example:**

```
x = 3**2
x = x+0.3
x%1
```

> ```
> result = 0.3000000000000007 | expected = 0.3
> ```

```
x = 3**199
x = x+0.3
x%1
```

> ```
> result = 0.0 |expected = 0.3
> ```

How can I improve the precision of the result / or find a clever way to check if the division give me an integer?

Comment: Read about [floating point representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point). With large enough floating point numbers there is not enough precision to track all the digits, hence the incorrect result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

not all fractions can be [represented exactly as floats](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html). your approach will therefore not work (as expected).

what you might try is the [`fractions`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html?highlight=fractions#module-fractions) module:

```
from fractions import Fraction

print(repr(Fraction(25, 5)))  # Fraction(5, 1)
```

this a way you could use `Fraction`:

```
def div_result_int(a, b):

    f = Fraction(a, b)
    return f.denominator == 1

print(div_result_int(a=25, b=5))  # True
print(div_result_int(a=25, b=3))  # False
```

Answer (score 2):

For integers `x` and `y`, the fraction `y/x` is an integer if and only if `y % x == 0`.  As long as `x` and `y` are integers, you don't have to worry about floating point errors or special numerical classes or anything.  Just make sure that `x` and `y` are actually represented as integers and not floats.  And since python can handle large integers, this works for integers longer than 64 bits, e.g:

```
> x = 17**100
> y = 17**200    
> y % x
0
> (y + 1) % x
1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [`float.is_integer()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#float.is_integer) to test for real or natural number value:

```
>>> x=3**23
>>> y=3**299
>>> res=x/y
>>> res
2.0631637441810574e-132
>>> res.is_integer()
False
>>> res=4.0000000000004
>>> res.is_integer()
False
>>> res=4.000
>>> res.is_integer()
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is the `decimal` module.

With your first example:

```
import decimal
x = decimal.Decimal('9.3')
x % 1
```

and the result will be `Decimal('0.3')`

With the second example, you would need to set the precision to 50:

```
decimal.getcontext().prec = 50
x = decimal.Decimal('171792506910670443678820376588540424234035840667.3')
```

again, the result of `x % 1` would be `Decimal('0.3')`